# Not able to fetch == symbol at the end of string into batch file argument

Tags: batch-file, rundeck

I'm trying to pass a parameter*(input)* from rundeck *(by creating a job)* through a command which calls the `.bat` file, the input contains an encrypted string which sometimes may contain `==` at the end of the string.

It collects the whole string but not able to collect the string inclusive of `==` at the end in the argument.

[image]

If the batch file itself its not able to collect the `==` at the end of string, then please suggest something else.

**disp**

```
echo on

set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2

IF %arg1%==display (
python D:\Python\displaymessage.py %arg1% %arg2%
) ELSE (
set Message="Something is wrong"
)


echo %arg1%
echo %arg2% >D:\Python\test.txt

pause
```

Comment: I've fixed the question to include the script content and image. Please note that in your image, the script as shown in `notepad` was named `disp`, it had either not been saved or did not have a `.cmd` or `.bat` extension, please confirm if an extension exists on that file! For your information, please use the following syntax in your batch files, `Set "arg1=%~1"`, `Set "arg2=%~2"` and `If /I "%arg1%"=="display"`, it would go some way to helping you now and in future.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in assigning %1 to Arg1. It will only slow the batchfile down. Batchfiles are opened, a line is read, closed. Repeatedly. Also the environment needs to be updated twice - and there is no point to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose each argument passed to the batch in quotes, then use

```
set "arg1=%~1"
set "arg2=%~2"

IF "%arg1%"=="display"
```

Where the `~` removes enclosing quotes, the quotes in the `set` ensure that no trailing spaces on the batch line are included into the value assigned, and the quotes in the `if` statement ensure that the two strings are correctly delimited for comparison.

Note also that `if /i .....` will perform a case-insensitive comparison if required.